# Change bar width in D3 Crossfilter example

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I'm looking at the [crossfliter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) example, and use some sample data to recreate bar charts, but with my data I want to have a narrower bar width, I believe it's in barPath function, but didn't figure out how to do it yet. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 463 of the page source, you have:

```
path.push('M', x(d.key), ',', height, 'V', y(d.value), 'h9V', height);
```

The `h9V` controls the width of each bar. Change to `h5V` to give a bit of a smaller bar. Bear in mind that if you still want each bar central to the relevant bin, you will have to make the following changes:

```
path.push('M', x(d.key) + 2, ',', height, 'V', y(d.value), 'h5V', height);
```

If you want to have a variable bar width, you could do something like this:

```
var barWidth = 0.6;

...

path.push('M', x(d.key) + Math.round((10-barWidth*10)/2), ',', height, 'V', y(d.value), 'h', barWidth*10,'V', height);
```

Note the `Math.round()` is just to make sure we get the closest whole pixel value.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's great!